# How to give VertSplit bar advanced styling in vim

Tags: vim

I'd like to know how to style the `VertSplit` property in vim, specifically to give the `VertSplit` different styling depending on the currently active window.
Currently I have this:
[image: vim, VertSplit varian 1]
Note that the left window is active.
Now what I would like to achive is that when I toggle the active window (`ctrl + w`, `ctrl + w`), that the VertSplit background and foreground colours change like in the second picture (essentially invert).
[image: vim, VertSplit variant two]
But I needed to modify my .vimrc manually for this to take effect.
In other words, I am looking for a similar property like with `statusline` and `statuslinenc` as seen in my `.vimrc`. I tried "`VertSplitnc`" but that did not have any effect.

Comment: There is no such thing.

Comment: If there is no such thing, there must be some workaround. Perhaps an `autocommand`?

Comment: Autocommand or not, you can't style `VertSplit`s individually. There is simply no way to do that. What you can do, though, is go to Vim's issue tracker and open a feature request. That said, if you are a ***VERY*** disciplined user and you ***NEVER*** have more than two vertical windows, and thus ***ONLY*** one vertical split, you may be able to cobble up something together… with, yes, an `autocommand`. Which sounds extremely simple to implement.

Comment: You can style `VertSplit`, see `:h hl-VertSplit`; but I doubt you can do this per active buffer